# how to return a stream from WCF service [nettcpbinding]?

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I have a WCF service and i want the client to get to receive an image from this service, by calling `client.GetStream();` that should return a `MemoryStream`

```
    public Stream GetStream()
    {
        Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            img = Image.FromStream(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Action = "image/jpeg";
            return ms;
        }
    }
```

IScreenShot interface :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IScreenShot
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetStream();
}
```

first exception i got was about the **MaxReceivedMessageSize**, then i increased it to 2MB.
now i have a new exception which is :

`Multiple headers with name 'Action' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' found.`

note that i followed the steps of this example :

[Sample Example(returning Image as Stream) from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221.aspx)
but the difference that im using NetTcpBinding.

is there something wrong with the code? or it doesn't work with nettcpbinding that way?

here's client :

```
public partial class ScreenImage : Form
{
    ScreenShotClient client;

    public ScreenImage(string baseAddress)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
        client = new ScreenShotClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
    }

    private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picBox.Image = Image.FromStream(client.GetStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: I know `FileStream` can't be serialized and have only had success with `MemoryStream`. What stream type are you returning? -- Also, here's another MSDN example for [returning streams in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx)

Comment: why not to return an array of bytes?

Comment: @BradChristie Im using MemoryStream.

Comment: @sleimanjneidi returning an array of bytes sounds more complicated, i prefer a stream, there's always a limit for message max array size i tried it and it didn't success.

Comment: @BradChristie +1 Thanks for your link .. you should post it as an answer, it worked now.